# Getting "Integrity constraint violation: 1452" in Laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-4, eloquent

I am using two pivot tables to store two different relations of a table. One relation works fine on insert. but the next one throws the following error. I don't know what's causing this.

> SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1452 Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`sdesk`.`approvers`, CONSTRAINT `approvers_user_id_foreign` FOREIGN KEY (`user_id`) REFERENCES `users` (`id`)) (SQL: insert into `approvers` (`user_id`, `request_id`, `updated_at`, `created_at`) values (2, 6, 2014-04-29 10:54:37, 2014-04-29 10:54:37))

Here's my code:

**UrequestsController.php**

```
 public function postCreate() { 
    $request = new Urequest;
    $request->vms = Input::get('vms');
    $request->location = Input::get('location');
    $request->descr = Input::get('descr');
    $request->status = Input::get('status');
    //$request->role_group = Input::get('team');
    $request->save();

    $ruser = new Ruser;
    $ruser->user_id = Input::get('userid');
    $ruser->urequest()->associate($request);
    $ruser->save();

    $approver = new Approver;
    $approver->user_id = Input::get('aid');
    $approver->urequest()->associate($request);
    $approver->save();


    return Redirect::to('users/dashboard')->with('message', 'Saved!');
}
```

**Approver.php**

```
 class Approver extends Eloquent {


protected $fillable = array('request_id', 'user_id');


public function urequest() {
    return $this->belongsTo('Urequest','request_id'); 
}

 }
```

**Ruser.php**

```
 class Ruser extends Eloquent {


protected $fillable = array('request_id', 'user_id');


public function urequest() {
    return $this->belongsTo('Urequest','request_id');
}

 }
```

**urequest.php**

```
 class Urequest extends Eloquent {

protected $table = 'requests';
protected $fillable = array('vms', 'location', 'descr', 'status');

public function ruser() {
    return $this->hasOne('Ruser'); 
}

public function approver() {
    return $this->hasOne('Approver'); 
}

 }
```

**Schema**

```
 Schema::create('requests', function($table)
{
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->string('vms', 20);
            $table->string('location', 20);
                    $table->string('descr', 255);
            $table->string('status', 20);
            $table->timestamps();
        });

 Schema::create('rusers', function($table)
    {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->integer('request_id')->unsigned();
        $table->foreign('request_id')->references('id')->on('requests');
        $table->integer('user_id')->unsigned();
        $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users');
        $table->timestamps();
    });

  Schema::create('approvers', function($table)
    {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->integer('request_id')->unsigned();
        $table->foreign('request_id')->references('id')->on('requests');
        $table->integer('user_id')->unsigned();
        $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users');
        $table->timestamps();
    });
```

Comment: Did you have user with id '2'?

Comment: Just now I saw. I deleted the user with id 2. Thanks post it to the answer

Comment: I had a similar problem. I had linked a "type" column to a lookup table, and was trying to leave it blank, which violated the foreign key constraint. I barely remembered that I had that second foreign key constraint in my schema, so I kept looking at my "user" foreign key and wondering what was wrong. I wanted to post as another possibility for others who may be banging their head against the wall.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"A foreign key constraint" usually fails when you don't have a row for the value(s) you are inserting/updating in the foreign table.

In this case you probably doesn't have a user_id of 2 in the users table or a request_id of 6 in the requests table.

**EDIT** just saw morawcik answered it in comments.